# Question about bias-variance trade off

Tags: variance, bias

[image]

This question is from a uni module about machine learning. I'm a bit stuck as I can't relate it to the bias-variance trade-off, to me the question implies all models have something to do with the trade off but I can only think of B being overfitted on its training data implying a low bias and high variance. I don't know how to explain A having both a high error in testing and training, and C I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me differently:

**B**. An example of **small bias and variance**.

**A**. A **large bias** (low quality at the training stage).

**C**. A **large variance** (losses for different data vary greatly).

But all this is said, assuming that the loss scale does not need to be taken literally. Otherwise, I also don't know how to interpret graphs A and C: absolutely the same losses on the test, which do not depend on the quality of training.

Comment: thanks :), I see where I was I wrong now, these graphs were confusing me for a while and I wasn't thinking about it properly